# Maximal number of singularities of an algebraic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

An algebraic curve defined by a polynomial of degree n can have at most (n−1)(n−2)/2 singularities. What is the maximal number of singularities of a curve in a k-dimensional space in terms of the degree of the k-1 polynomial equations defining the curve?

P.S.: The comment of Mohan posted below gives an upper bound on the number of singularities by using the fact the the geometric genus is non-negative. So, I could reformulate my question as follows. Are there space curves of genus 0 (or 1) so that the upper bound (possibly minus 1) is attained? given for granted that the curve is irreducible.

Comment: Do you know that not every curve $C$ in $\mathbb P^k$ can be defined by exactly $k-1$ polynomials? If $C$ has this property, then it is called a (*global*) *complete intersection*. So do you want to restrict to complete intersections, or do you want an answer in terms of the degrees of a generating set for the ideal of $C$? For complete intersections, I'd expect there to be an upper bound easily obtained from Bezout's theorem. (I don't know if it would be sharp.)

Comment: Yes, I can imagine it. Let me restrict to complete intersections.

Comment: The crudest estimate for this is the arithmetic genus (the number you wrote for plane curves), since the geometric genus is non-negative. So, if you have polynomials of degrees $d_i, 1\leq i<k$ defining an irreducible curve in $k$-space, the maximum number of singular points is $d_1\cdots d_{k-1} (\sum d_i-k-1)$.

Comment: Did you miss one half in the expression?

Comment: since the union of 3 general lines in the plane has 3 singularities, and has degree 3, perhaps you want to restrict to irreducible curves?

Comment: mohan seems to have given the formula for 2g-2 when he probably meant to give one for g.

Comment: To roy smith. Yes, irreducible over complex fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum number of singularities, properly counted, is equal to the arithmetic genus. For example, take the curve $x_1^2=x_2,\, x_2^2=x_3,\dots,x_{k-1}^2=x_k$. This curve has a rational parametrization. Thus, the geometric genus is equal to zero and the number of singularities (at infinity) is equal to the arithmetic genus.