# Space curves with singularities of multiplicity $n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In plane curves, a singularity of multiplicity $n$ reduces the geometric genus by $n(n-1)/2$. This makes sense. Indeed, if we slightly move a line, we get $n-1$ intersections, two lines $(n-1)+(n-2)$ and so on.  How can one extend this reasoning to space curves?

This question is related to this other one,
[Maximal number of singularities of an algebraic curve](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306659/maximal-number-of-singularities-of-an-algebraic-curve).
A simple way for having a plane curve of degree $n$ with maximal number of singularities is taking the coefficients of every monomial of degree less than $n$ equal to zero. This gives a $(n-1)(n-2)/2$ degenerate singularity in $(0,0)$. Is it possible to do the same for space curves by choosing an appropriate degenerate singularity?

Comment: You are only considering *ordinary* singularities (the tangent cone is reduced). In higher codimension, the multiplicity alone does *not* determine the singularity, apart for multiplicity $2$ (nodes). For instance, there are both planar and non-planar triple points, so finding a closed formula becomes more involved.

Comment: I am aware that the multiplicity is not enough and I was wondering if there is a simple way for determining the singularity. For example, by grouping the intersecating lines that are planar at the intersection point.